# error NG8002: Can't bind to 'owlDateTimeTrigger' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-services, angular-schematics, angular-webpack

HI i need to add owlDateTimeTrigger in angular 16 microfrontent but it show error. please check the below screenshot.

Code:

<ng-template #childtemplateSheduleTime let-data>

<input [(ngModel)]="data.pipe" [min]="smModel.min" [max]="smModel.max" class="form-control"
placeholder="Select Date and Time" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="pipelineDtPicker1"
[owlDateTime]="pipelineDtPicker1">
<span [owlDateTimeTrigger]="pipelineDtPicker1" class="calender-icon">
<owl-date-time [startAt]="smModel.startAt" #pipelineDtPicker1>

Thanks

[image]

Comment: U didn't even take a good print screen.... but I will ask you if your element is like this <owl-date-time #dt></owl-date-time>. Post code not pictures.

Comment: <ng-template #childtemplateSheduleTime let-data>
          <div>
              <input [(ngModel)]="data.pipe" [min]="smModel.min" [max]="smModel.max" class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Select Date and Time" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="pipelineDtPicker1"
                  [owlDateTime]="pipelineDtPicker1">
              <span [owlDateTimeTrigger]="pipelineDtPicker1" class="calender-icon"><i
                      class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
              <owl-date-time [startAt]="smModel.startAt" #pipelineDtPicker1></owl-date-time></div>
      </ng-template>

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the modules `OwlDateTimeModule` and `OwlNativeDateTimeModule` imported in your `app.module.ts`

```
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
...

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        OwlDateTimeModule,
        OwlNativeDateTimeModule,
        ...
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

[stackblitz Demo not by me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/owl-datetimepicker?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: thanks for your reply but it is for angular 16 microfrontend standalone.

Comment: @manishjadli could you add these imports to the imports array of the standalone component where you are getting this error, it might resolve it!

Comment: i already use it this steps. but not get success show same above screenshot error. this demo is angular 6 but i use angular 16 standalone.